# How to use binwalk to recursively extract all files to a folder

Tags: computer-forensics, ctf

I'm trying to resolve a matryoshka_doll problem. I already solved it by creating a script
using unzip, but know I would like to use binwalk to achieve the same effect. Searching through the `binwalk --help` I didn't find anything useful, but I could have missed something.

This is the command I'm using: `binwalk -Me dolls.jpg`

Which gives me a structure like:

```
   ./dolls_extracted/doll_2 
   ./dolls_extracted/doll_2_extracted
   ./dolls_extracted/doll_2_extracted/doll_3
```

However I want a structure like this:

```
   ./doll_2 
   ./doll_3
```

Can this be done using only binwalk ?

Answer (score 1):

Binwalk does not have an option to extract files recursively to a specific folder, but you can achieve the desired output using a combination of binwalk and other command-line tools.

Here is one way to extract all files recursively to a folder using binwalk:

1. Run binwalk with the -e option to extract the files:

   binwalk -e dolls.jpg

This will create a directory called "_dolls.jpg.extracted" in the current directory, which contains all the extracted files.

2. Use the find command to recursively move all files to a new folder:

   find _dolls.jpg.extracted/ -type f -exec mv {} ./ ;

This will find all files in the "_dolls.jpg.extracted" directory and move them to the current directory. The directory structure will be flattened, so you will have all the files in the same directory.

3. Remove the empty directories:

   find _dolls.jpg.extracted/ -type d -empty -delete

This will find all empty directories in the "_dolls.jpg.extracted" directory and delete them.

4. Rename the extracted files:

   rename 's/./_dolls.jpg.extracted//' ''

This will remove the "_dolls.jpg.extracted/" prefix from the filenames.